# Why does astype on a pandas column of datetime convert to nanoseconds in POSIX time?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
import datetime
time = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, minute=1)
rows = pd.DataFrame( 
{ 
  "id": [1], 
  "time": [time], 
})  
print(rows.time.values.astype(int))
```

gives the output

```
array([60000000000])
```

This appears to be in nanoseconds, and I was wondering why it defaults to that? Is it possible to have `astype` return seconds by default? Currently, i have to divide by `10**9`.

Comment: why? because that's how it's implemented I guess... "*Is it possible to have astype return seconds by default?*" - no, but you can just divide by 10**9 ;-)

Comment: I believe it's because Pandas datetime precision defaults to nanoseconds.

Comment: FWIW, you could simplify the example: `t = pd.Series([time]); t.astype(int)[0]` -> `60000000000`